# I get this error while entering my secret seed phrase on the solana CLI

Tags: solana-cli

I got this error while entering my secret seed phrase after pressing enter on the solana CLI: Error: Dynamic program error: Can't get mnemonic from seed phrases

I also double checked that my secret seed phrase is correct

Comment: Can you share the cli command you used? (Obviously hide the secret)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using your seed phrase (Collection of words) or your private key? If you are using the CLI the most common setup is using a file system wallet which is your private key in a JSON file (a bunch of numbers). Common usage would be to have the private key saved as a file called wallet.json which you can reference as `wallet.json` in your cli command.

Comment: Hello, I didn’t use a file system wallet in fact I used a paper wallet. I was trying to create a staking account and while I tried to create it I had to type the secret seed phrase which then lead to the error message. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can create a secret key from your phrase. Save the phrase in a file and run this command:
```solana-keygen recover 'prompt:?key=0/0' -o seedPhrase.json```

This should create a JSON file that contains your secret key, you can then use this for work in the CLI.

Comment: And how exactly is it going to help me with creating my stake account? These are the following commands that i'll have to insert to be creating a staking account: solana stake-authorize <STAKE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS> \
    --stake-authority <KEYPAIR> --new-stake-authority <PUBKEY> \
    --fee-payer <KEYPAIR>

Comment: Ohhhhh, I didn't mean to create a stake account, I meant that I wanted to set a staking account. Sorry for the confusion lol

Comment: You would be able to use the JSON file that you create in all the places where you have <KEYPAIR> in your above example.